# Azure - Creating Service Principal with Tenant Admin Permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to provision `Azure AD Domain Service` by executing an ARM template in terrafrom. To let terrafrom access Azure, I have created a `service principal` using below script :

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Owner" --scopes="/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxfca38"
```

and then gave the Client ID and Secret to terrafrom.

The problem is, when I execute the script azure gives me an error saying :

```
code":"BadRequest", "message": "The user xxxxx-80b is not the tenant admin of tenant xxxxxx-xxxxxfca38.
```

However, when I login to Azure portal using my email and password, I can create `AZ AD Domain Service` without any error.

How do I create a service principal with right privilege for performing such operation? I initially thought `--role="Owner"` should be sufficient.

Alternatively, it is possible to get Client ID and Secret of the same account which I use to login to Azure portal?

P.S : I am using a personal account in azure which is not linked to any organization AD.

Comment: right, you need `Owner` permission on the subscription and permission to create applications in Azure AD. I've never personally seen this error, so wouldn't be able to tell why it is being thrown or how to workaround this, but consider checking if you actually are an owner on that subscription, or grant yourself `User Access Administrator` permissions over the subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no personal account with a subscription to test. Just refer to the steps below to have a try.

> I am using a personal account in azure which is not linked to any organization AD.

When you login to the azure portal, actually there is a default directory, but if you create the AD App in the Azure AD directly, you can not select the single-tenant app.

1.Navigate to the Azure AD in the portal -> `Create a directory`(we don't use the directory later, just becasuse the operation will let the `Default Directory` to appear).

[image]

When you create the directory successfully, close the browser(not refresh) and open a new one, login to the portal, click the button as below, you will find the `Default Directory`.

[image]

2.Navigate to the subscription in the portal -> check the `Directory`, then you will know which directory your subscription is located, also make sure `My role` is `Owner` or `User Access Administrator`, otherwise, you will not be able to run the command `az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Owner" --scopes="/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxfca38"` successfully.

[image]

3.If your subscription is in the `Default directory`, you can navigate to the Azure AD -> `Properties` -> set `Access management for Azure resources` to `Yes`, then you will be the `User Access Administrator`.(If you are already be the `Owner` or `User Access Administrator`, ignore this step.)

4.Then login the Azure CLI with the command below, specify the `tenant` with the `tenant ID`, which the subscription located in.

```
az login --tenant <tenant>
```

5.Run the command `az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Owner" --scopes="/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxfca38"`, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. in your second step, I have checked my subscription role and it says "Account admin". This is a free subscription that I have from Microsoft. I have done step 3 and still getting the same error. I will try with another account and different subscription.

Comment: @Benjamin I have not used the free subscription, please try to grant yourself as an `Owner` in the subscription -> Access control (IAM), and make sure you do the operations in the correct tenant, it is important.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the complete answer:**

*You get the "Bad Request" error because the Service Principle needs to have Global Admin Rights in the Tenant.*

For the complete TF Template to run you need the correct permissions at both the Tenant and Subscription level.

- Subscription: Owner
- Tenant: Global Admin

Joy already showed how to set the Subscription Owner property so I won't repeat it here but you do need to make sure you are in the correct Directory/Tenant context if you have more than one.

**Assigning the Global Admin Role to a Service Principle:**

In the portal navigate to:

```
Azure Active Directory
  -> Roles and Administrators
   -> Search for and select "Global Administrator"
    -> Click on "Global Administrator"
```

At this point you will see a list of all users and Service Principles currently assigned this role.

Here is the non-obvious part. When you click on "Add Assignments" a blade pops up on the right with a list of the AD users and groups in the current Tenant but no Service Principles. You need to search for the SP by name - it will pop up in the search results. Select it like you would a user and "Add". The SP will now show up in the earlier list of users assigned the GA role.

Once I did this the Terraform Template was able to create the AAD DS instance.